# The interpretation of conditional probability minus overall probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Given two events $X$ and $Y$, do we have any existing mathematical or statistical interpretation of the term $P(Y|X) - P(Y)$?

I feel that it can tell how the occurrence of $X$ "boosts" the occurrence of $Y$, but could not find a directly related reference.

---

Note: If it is not "probability" but "entropy", this is related to mutual information.